# Probability of getting into at least one university given grades and scores

Tags: probability, statistics, applications, independence

A number of websites offer tools which estimate odds of being accepted to universities given grades and standardized test scores, based on applicant data. The question of calculating odds of getting into at least one university *given their acceptance rates* [has already been asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931726/probability-of-getting-into-at-least-one-university-given-acceptance-rate-for-ea), but as mentioned in the comments for that question, the events are not independent, because all acceptances are dependent on scores. Given acceptance rates after factoring in scores, can a more conclusive statistic be calculated?

Example:

Say a student is applying to three schools, $a$, $b$ and $c$, with $A$, $B$ and $C$ representing acceptance into each school respectively as events. Factoring in test scores, $P(A)$ is 54.9%, $P(B)$ is 24.87%, $P(C)$is 19.95%. What is the probability of getting into at least one school? Two? All of them? Confidence intervals?

Moveover, what impact does the quasi-dependence have on the results?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information given. For instance if the universities have the same rule for admission that your grades are $\geq t_i$ for some threshold $t_i$ for individual university $i$ then the probability to get into one will be $\max(P_i)$ the same as probability to get into the easiest one.

Comment: The probability of getting into any of the universities is dependent on the *exact* scores and grades scored, not maximums or minimums. An increase or decrease in either scores or grades would change all probabilities listed.

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific on what the rules for being accepted to an education are. It is not very clear to me. Do the different universities have different rules for setting the thresholds on scores and grades? Is it enough to have good enough grades if your scores are too low and vice versa or does both scores and grade requirements need to be fulfilled?

Comment: In the United States at least, universities accept applications including standardized test scores (like the SAT and ACT), grades from high school, essays, and other information. To simplify the question, assume that the only factors that matter are scores and grades, and that the probability of being accepted is dependent on these data. For example, applying to Example University with a GPA (grades) of 3.6 and SAT (exam) of 2000, the probability of being accepted might be 36%. But with better grades and scores, say, a GPA of 3.9 and SAT of 2200, you might have a 63% chance of being admitted.

Comment: Each university has its own standards, but there is no minimum threshold to be accepted. In fact, a student with a 3.5 GPA and 1900 SAT might be accepted to Example University, while a student with a 4.0 GPA and 2200 SAT might be rejected. It's entirely probabilistic. The most important things to know are that higher scores and grades mean better chances of being accepted, and that each university has its own distributions.